# How to add Matplotlib live graph in my html page?

Tags: html, python-3.x

How can I add a matplotlib live graph in my html page?

```py
from psutil import cpu_percent
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


print(cpu_percent())


frame_len = 200
y = []
def animate(i):
    y.append(cpu_percent())

    if len(y) <= frame_len:
        plt.cla()
        plt.plot(y, 'r', label = 'Real-Time Cpu')

    plt.tight_layout()

ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, interval= 1000)
#grp = plt.show()
```